# How to remove categories from category dropdown if no products within the category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to be able to hide categories in a categories drop down menu (wordpress + woocommerce) if the number of products within the category is 0. Does somebody know how to do this? I tried this below:

```
wp_dropdown_categories('hide_empty=0');
```

and

```
wp_dropdown_categories('excludes=0');
```

Comment: Did you mean `wc_dropdown_categories`?

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_dropdown_categories( array|string $args = '' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/)

[image]

```php
wp_dropdown_categories('hide_if_empty=true');
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it is still display categories with 0 products in the drop down